# Cannot find node_module less in dev environnement

Tags: css, symfony, less

In a symfony2 project, I use assetic with less filter.
Everything is ok in prod environnement, the command assetic:dump generates corrects css files.
But when I render the page in dev envrionnement, my css files tell me that the less module could not be find.
It looks like that:

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
"/usr/bin/node" "/tmp/assetic_lessb45F2E"

Error Output:

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module "less"
```

My config.yml seems to be good

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

My project is served by Apache runned by www-data user.

I tried to chmod 777 my node_modules folder just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Your config does not respect the right hierarchy, and no need to specify `.less` extension, ir-s default config for `less` filter :

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    node: /usr/bin/node
    node_paths: /usr/lib/node_modules
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less: ~
```

Check /usr/bin path if node binary is in there (or linked), but maybe you should define this binary (looks like you locally installed node) :

```
node: /usr/local/bin/node
node_paths: /usr/LOCAL/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I changed my config to respect the hierarchy, but it doesn't solve the problem.
I've checked my node path and it's correct, less module is also installed with global option.

Comment: So try /usr/lib/node_modules for node_paths

Comment: It seems better, I have no more error, but my css files are empty.

Comment: this is another issue. what happens if you generate them from a shell command with less ?

Comment: It works as expected, either with less command, or with assetic:dump

Comment: CSS files are no more empty ?